# Integration Tests with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, continuous-integration

**What I have:**
I'm developing a microservice, using Spring Boot with Web and SpringMyBatis.
For CI integration tests I'll use a remote MySQL database, for local integration tests I'll use H2. I've got different application.yml file for both databases.

**My problem:**
Since I want to create integration tests that will run on both databases, and I'll have to use different JDBC drivers (my tests will check directly on database what has been inserted/modified), what's the best way to do that? 
Could be a solution to use Spring JDBC to query my database, so that my datasource will be "picked" directly from application properties?

Comment: Ideally you need just one DataSource configured from a spring profile. Thus you can switch it on fly choosing necessary one for your CI.

Comment: Yes, that was my idea. So I need to configure my DataSource also on my @Config file and then retrieve the driver from that one?

Comment: Kind of. The only difference is Driver, connection URL and credentials.

Comment: Any idea on how to do that? I've got different connection URL and credentials on different application.yml. But haven't got any idea on how to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot supports loading of different property files for different environments. Just create a proper `application-<profile>.properties` (or `.yml` and Spring Boot will load the appropriate one.

For instance in a `application-qa.properties` you specify the following

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:<remote-host>/db
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
```

If you want to use an embedded H2 for everything else you can omit configuration as when H2 is on the class path Spring Boot will auto configure an in-memory H2 for you.

Now when running the integration tests specify `qa` as the active profile and you will automatically be connected to the configured datasource. You can use Maven Profiles to select the active Spring Profile.

You don't need multiple `DataSource` beans in your configuration as Spring Boot will only configure the 1 requested.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned it's good to use spring profile. Define 2 DataSources annotated with `@Profile("dev")` and `@Profile("qa")` and specify desired driver/connections url/credentials.

See [the example](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) (different datasources like you need) and/or [the example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/) to get more info

Comment: Ok, I got your answer. But since I'm actually using spring profiles to load different application properties, and on my application property I've already got all my driver data (url, user, pass..), Is there a way to recover THAT particular datasource?

Comment: It's possible but I don't know your configs and project structure. You have to change something in the code you didn't post

Comment: Ok, it works if I'll use the datasource this way: `@Autowired DataSource datasource`. It will pick the datasource set by the correct profile application.yml. Thanks for your hints!

Comment: Don't define multiple beans... Just add 2 different `application-<proflile>.properties` instead of multiple beans. That way spring boot will load the appropriate configuration file and configure the datasource. No need to make it more complex then that.

Comment: @M.Deinum in general I agree (+1) but there are cases when it's easier to define conditional bean than copy properties.

Comment: First one should work with the features of the framework, defining multiple beans (the same beans basically) and try to do mapping for them generally makes things complexer and is working around the framework.